# Changing jQuery function to page load

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can anyone tell me how to change the following statement which is currently controlled by a radio button to a document load function.

Basically I want the slide div to slide out from the left to right when the page loads.
jQuery:

```
jQuery(function() { 
jQuery('#slide').hide(); 
jQuery(':radio[name=radiobutton]').click(function() { 
    var value = $(this).val(); 
    if (value === 'Y') { 
        jQuery('#slide').show('slow'); 
    } else if (value === 'N') { 
        jQuery('#slide').hide('slow'); 
    } 
});
```

HTML:

```
<div id="slide" class="alpha60">

<p class="statement_style_head">Content goes here</p>

<p class="statement_style_text">A line or two of text goes here </p>

</div>
```

Comment: You can try this link for sliding examples: http://www.learningjquery.com/2009/02/slide-elements-in-different-directions

Answer (score 0):

$(document).ready({. Your staff. });

Answer (score 0):

One way is to just click it on load like so `$('input[name=radiobutton]').click();` or `$('input[name=radiobutton]').trigger('click');`

The other would be to place your code inside a function and call that function on load.

```
function showSomething(){
   // code here
}

showSomething();
```

Answer (score 0):

Document.ready is kind of onload for javascript , it waits till everything is ready and then executes...your code , it safe and best practices for onload

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("divid").animate({top:'10px', bottom:0}, 3000);
    });
```

Comment: @NewB i just moved the code...in document.ready , you can refine it the way you want...

Comment: We're getting closer but I want to get rid of the Value's all together, I just want the div to slide out when the page loads and is not dependent on anything.

Comment: @enewB make your div relative position and then use animate function from jquery http://api.jquery.com/animate/ , you can do all great animations there...

Comment: get offset location and start animation and stop at after some pixel it should be straig forward